# Angularjs $http.get().then and binding to a list

Tags: angularjs, get, promise

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="document in DisplayDocuments()" ng-class="IsFiltered(document.Filtered)">
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="docChecked" id="doc_{{document.Id}}" ng-model="document.Filtered" /></span>
    <span>{{document.Name}}</span>
</li>
```

I bind this list in my controller, to this:

```
$scope.Documents = $http.get('/Documents/DocumentsList/' + caseId).then(function(result) {
    return result.data;
});
```

When this runs, I dont get any results. when I remove the `then` method, I get three empty lines, making the count OK, but no information is displayed.

I know "everthing" else works, since I previously populated the list with jQuery, what am I doing wrong?

Here's the response from the server:

```
{Id:3f597acf-a026-45c5-8508-bc2383bc8c12, Name:ZZ_BL0164_Skisse BL0164_945111.pdf, Order:1,…}
{Id:46f51f1f-02eb-449a-9824-8633e8ae7f31, Name:ZB_BL0201_Firmaattest BL0201_945111.pdf, Order:1,…}
{Id:fddd1979-c917-4b32-9b83-b315f66984ed, Name:ZA_BL0228_Legitimasjonsskjema BL0228_945111.pdf,…}
```

Comment: I normally use .get(...).success(function (data) {}); maybe you can add console.log(result) and see what it outputs? I'd also make sure that the url you call is well formed. what is caseId?

Comment: I have tried that as well, just thought this looked better, and was easier to follow, which is why I wanted to give it a go. I have seen people using both, but cant get this way to work.

Comment: You are binding `Document` to your scope, but using `DisplayDocuments()` in the `ng-repeat` where does `DisplayDocuments()` originate from?

Comment: I do something simmilar in a factory. However instead of `$scope.Documents` I  have `var mypromise` and I set `$scope.Documents`in the then/success part.

Comment: I have a service that should return documents, which is why I wanted to avoid setting $scope.documents in then/success part, but looks like I have to do something like that.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

$http methods return a promise, which can't be iterated, so you have to attach the results to the scope variable through the callbacks:

```
$scope.documents = [];
$http.get('/Documents/DocumentsList/' + caseId)
  .then(function(result) {
    $scope.documents = result.data;
});
```

Now, since this defines the `documents` variable only after the results are fetched, you need to initialise the `documents` variable on scope beforehand: `$scope.documents = []`. Otherwise, your ng-repeat will choke.

This way, ng-repeat will first return an empty list, because `documents` array is empty at first, but as soon as results are received, ng-repeat will run again because the `documents``have changed in the success callback.

Also, you might want to alter you ng-repeat expression to:

```
<li ng-repeat="document in documents" ng-class="IsFiltered(document.Filtered)">
```

because if your `DisplayDocuments()` function is making a call to the server, than this call will be executed many times over, due to the $digest cycles.

Comment: So I can only return a promise to scope when I am not returning an array? Displaydocuments does not make the call to the server, thanks for the heads up anyway.

Comment: I meant, if you write `$scope.documents = $http.get(...)` than the `documents` will reference a promise (from the $q service), because that's what $http service returns, a promise.

Comment: Yes, understood that, but i thought angular was able to resolve that promise automagically? Apparently i'm wrong.

Comment: You've probably mistaken the $http service for [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource), which does return a (iterative) promise, but the promise is automatically resolved when results are back.

Comment: Honestly didnt know about $resource, but it looks exactly like what im looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I have been stuck with this for two hours, thanks for sharing the answer mate

Answer (score 26):

Promise returned from `$http` can not be binded directly (I dont exactly know why).
I'm using wrapping service that works perfectly for me:

```
.factory('DocumentsList', function($http, $q){
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/DocumentsList').success(function(data){
        d.resolve(data);
    });
    return d.promise;
});
```

and bind to it in controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope, DocumentsList) {
    $scope.Documents = DocumentsList;
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE!:**

In Angular 1.2 auto-unwrap promises was removed. 
See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how, but man, you've ended my misery. Thank you!

Comment: @Davion and anyone else wondering what is going on in this code, $http returns an http promise which wraps the response object, not the actual data. That's why you can't "bind" directly to it. Here, the $q service is being used to create a new promise that is being resolved to the actual data. Working with that promise, the controller can get at the actual data rather than just the http response. BTW, $http _success_ and _error_ methods are deprecated, so using _then_ is now recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you get `promise` on `$http.get`.

Try to use followed flow:

```
<li ng-repeat="document in documents" ng-class="IsFiltered(document.Filtered)">
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="docChecked" id="doc_{{document.Id}}" ng-model="document.Filtered" /></span>
    <span>{{document.Name}}</span>
</li>
```

Where `documents` is your array.

```
$scope.documents = [];

$http.get('/Documents/DocumentsList/' + caseId).then(function(result) {
    result.data.forEach(function(val, i) { 
        $scope.documents.push(/* put data here*/);
    });
}, function(error) {
    alert(error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `success()` call back

```
$http.get('/Documents/DocumentsList/' + caseId).success(function (result) {
    $scope.Documents = result;
});
```

But now since `Documents` is an array and not a promise, remove the `()`

```
<li ng-repeat="document in Documents" ng-class="IsFiltered(document.Filtered)"> <span>
           <input type="checkbox" name="docChecked" id="doc_{{document.Id}}" ng-model="document.Filtered" />
        </span>
 <span>{{document.Name}}</span>

</li>
```