# How to bind a select element to angular object?

Tags: angularjs

This is my first ever code written in angular after a 2-hour investigation and code play. Seems my knockout background doesn't help here. Please have a look at my code :

```
var dc = angular.module("DC", []);
dc.factory("incomeCategories",function($rootScope, $http) {
    var categories = {};

    $http.get("app/Categories/GetIncomeCategories").success(function(data) {
        categories = data;
    });
    return categories;
});
dc.controller("CategoriesController", function($scope, $http, incomeCategories) {
    $scope.incomeCategories = incomeCategories;
    $scope.incomeCategory = {};
});
```

Now here is my select option :

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="incomeCategory" ng-options="ic.title for ic in incomeCategories"></select>
```

I think at the time of binding the incomeCategories is not loaded. But it should update the UI as it get populated right? like observables in knockout.

Comment: The problem (unverified) looks to be that you're returning `categories` as empty (call this object a), and when the AJAX call returns, you set `categories` to reference `data` (object b). That doesn't mean that object a is updated.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimIsaksson I removed the loading from service and put it inside of my controller then it worked as expected. I still haven't figured out why the previous one wasn't working though. Is this best practice to directly communicate with you back-end inside your controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218579/56465 for a solution.

If you are using AngularJS 1.2 and want to use a simple

```
return $http.get("app/Categories/GetIncomeCategories")
```

in your factory, then you might want to turn on

```
$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)
```

as mentioned in the [AngularJS 1.2 migration guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises)